# Как показывать определенное кол-во колонок bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как показывать определенное кол-во колонок bootstrap, а при нажатии показывать остальные колонки.
Я по умолчанию скрыл все колонки, а с помощью jquery показываю их при инажатии на кнопку.
Нужно что бы на странице показывалось 6 колонок, а при нажатии открывались остальные.
P.S Не могу убрать    `d-none` с первых 6 колонок, так как эти колонки у меня вывоодятся в оригинале циклом     `foreach`

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.col-lg-4').removeClass('d-none');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="photo">
    <div class="container mb-4">
        <h1>фото</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row g-4">
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://clck.ru/U7DMw">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://clck.ru/U7DMw">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://clck.ru/U7DMw">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://clck.ru/U7DMw">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://clck.ru/U7DMw">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://clck.ru/U7DMw">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://clck.ru/U7DMw">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://clck.ru/U7DMw">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="d-grid mb-5">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-rounded">Открыть ещё</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того, как вы циклом создадите вашу разметку, чтобы показать `n` элементов, в JQuery можно воспользоваться фильтром `:lt(n)` для выбора первых `n` элементов, удовлетворяющих селектору, как:

```
$('.col-lg-4:lt(6)').removeClass('d-none');
```

```js
$('.col-lg-4:lt(6)').removeClass('d-none');

$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.col-lg-4').removeClass('d-none');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="photo">
  <div class="container mb-4">
    <h1>фото</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row g-4">
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="d-grid mb-5">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-rounded">Открыть ещё</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

или выбрать `n` элементов из коллекции, которую возвращает выборка по селектору, как:

```
$('.col-lg-4').slice(0, 6).removeClass('d-none');
```

```js
$('.col-lg-4').slice(0, 6).removeClass('d-none');
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.col-lg-4').removeClass('d-none');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="photo">
  <div class="container mb-4">
    <h1>фото</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row g-4">
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 d-none">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="d-grid mb-5">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-rounded">Открыть ещё</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

или при создании разметки первым `n` элементам не присваивать класс `d-none`.